# Is there any way to schedule mail using gmail api?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail, gmail-api

I am currently working gmail Queries of "GTLGmail" is there any way or query to schedule mails.

I had gone through https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides but I am unable to find any solution for the same.

Comment: You can't schedule emails through gmail itself, so there would be no api feature explicitly allowing this. You could however have your email go to your own server until the specified time where it would send using the gmail api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gmail API has no scheduling functionality. You could solve it by temporarily holding the email on your own server as Jorden mentioned in the comments, or you could look into the [App Engine Cron Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron).

Answer (score 1):

You can try Mail Scheduler (https://github.com/siquylee/mail-scheduler) Mail Scheduler is Gmail toolbox for sending scheduled emails and recurring emails using Google Spreadsheet & Forms. Mail Scheduler is NOT a web app or browser extension. If you are familiar with Microsoft Office, you can think Mail Scheduler is Excel macro-enabled workbook.

P.S. I'm the author of Mail Scheduler