# Gmail now supports scheduling emails, how does is work using the gmail rest api, or is the api supporting this feature?

Tags: c#, vb.net, rest, gmail, gmail-api

My app uses the Gmail API to send Emails programmatically. Since Google supports scheduling EMails in Gmail, i am searching for a solution to use this feature via the Gmail REST API.

Does the Gmail REST API supports **scheduled** EMails?

I can't find anything on their Site Gmail API Google Developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217346/is-there-any-way-to-schedule-mail-using-gmail-api) that **Gmail API has no scheduling functionality** therefore as well as using Gmail REST API. You could probably [Scheduling Tasks With Cron for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217346/is-there-any-way-to-schedule-mail-using-gmail-api) that allows you to configure regularly scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals.