# Scheduling an email with the Gmail API

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217346/is-there-any-way-to-schedule-mail-using-gmail-api) from 2016, however at that time Gmail itself did not support scheduled sending of emails.

Now that you can schedule messages to send later directly from Gmail, I was wondering if there was a way to do it with their API.

Interestingly, scheduled emails appear as message objects when calling `messages.list`, but they do not contain any labels.

Any help would be appreciated! And if it's not possible at the moment, it would be awesome to get a reply from someone at Google about when this will become possible (I believe they officially endorse the gmail-api tag to StackOverflow)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a time-based trigger will work--even if you write the code to store email send data and then build something that regularly checks whether it's time for an email to be sent. See [Google's documentation on triggers](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers), and you'll notice that time-based triggers aren't available for Gmail scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no Gmail API endpoint for scheduling the sending of emails directly.

One workaround would be to write a script in Google Apps Script (https://script.google.com) which handles the composing of the email you wish to send, as well as a function to send the mail via the API. You can then use the built-in 'Apps Script Project Triggers' feature to trigger the function to run on a schedule; for example on action/event or at a specific/repeated time.

[Button for adding trigger to Apps Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmPyg.png)