# Ho to schedule emails using the Google API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Since [April 2020](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/gmails-scheduling-tool-to-send-email-messages-later-is-one-of-our-favorite-things/) Gmail supports schedule sending an email. But I can't find anything related to this in the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send).

Is it possible to schedule an email with the Gmail API?

PS:
Although this question has been [asked in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217346/is-there-any-way-to-schedule-mail-using-gmail-api), they were posted before the functionality was available, hence a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a request to expose the feature to the API. You can indicate you would like this feature by adding a star ("⭐") next to the issue number here:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/140922183

Answer (score 0):

yes the Gmail web application may support scheduling but there is no API endpoint for this.

Your going to have to code this yourself.